# Pub/Sub vs Bidirectional Streaming in gRPC for chat service

Tags: redis, grpc

Which one is more suitable between Pub/Sub (redis) with server streaming and Bidirectional Streaming without pub/sub to make chat service?

Both works well, but I want to know the pros and cons on each side.

I found some repos which use pub/sub way instead of Bidirectional Streaming, I just wonder why